# Integrating Google Maps data to a game. How?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have a Game idea which uses Google Maps data, and I wanna know how I can do this.

The idea is:
A online war game that is based on the localization of the players' phones, which I would use Google Maps to get the cordinates and draw the map on the screen, so I can draw icons on the map (ammo, medicines and etc). And when the player's cordinates meet the item's cordinates it goes to the player, for example.

Simplifying, what I have in mind is: I need to get player's cordinates and map images from Google Maps. How I can do that?

Sorry for the bad english.

Thanks,
Luís Henrique.

Answer (score 4):

I recommend starting with this tutorial.

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidLocationAPI/article.html

That will get your feet wet in loading up maps.

Then use this tutorial at the bottom it will reference itemized overlay which will enable you to add all the weapons and respond to events when you click on it.

http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html

Your game sounds fun!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can check [cloudmade's specialist tools](http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/show/specialist-tools)

Also there is [static maps api from cloudmade](http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/show/static-maps)

U can check a list of apps/games made using this [here](http://cloudmade.com/application-gallery)